# Generate two standard Gaussian random variables for 100.000 samples

Tags: python, random, statistics, sampling

Generate two standard Gaussian random variables for 100.000 samples. Makesure you generate the random variables correctly by checking their means and variances.

I have a question like this. İt can be make in MATLAB but I want to make it by using python. But I didn't understand the question. What does it mean 'for 100.000 samples' ? What commands should I use to make this in Python?

Comment: The wording is obscure. You would have to ask whoever wrote that for clarification. It might be interpreted as Making two random samples, each of 100,000 numbers and then looking at the mean and variance of each set of 100,000 numbers. As to how -- numpy has one solution. The built-in random module has another. It should be easy enough to google how these work and then decide which works best for you.

Comment: Here other part of question. I think teacher asks a question like you said in the first part. İsN't it? Through your simulation data, determine the covariance and the correlation coefficient between the generated data. Compare your values with Matlab’s cov and corrcoef functions and observe that they agree, or the functions available from the libraries of your programming platform. We assume that Matlab or your random variable generator generates uncorrelated values. Hence, you should observe that the covariance and correlation coefficient to be close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
from random import gauss

# Expected mean
mu = 0
# Expected variance
var = 1

# Sample list
samples = [ gauss(mu, var) for i in range(100000) ]

# Printing average and variance of samples

# Compare it with (mu)
print( np.mean(samples) )

# Compare it with (var)
print( np.var(samples) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code you shared. On the other side of the problem, he wants something from me, like a simulation. Shouldn't I be producing 100,000 numbers for this? Do I get the question wrong?

Comment: @YusufUçan Yes you should produce. You can do that by enclosing this code inside a function and then return the `samples` as the output

Comment: Thanks again. I will try.